# Resize and change position of View while it is playing a video

Tags: android, video

My Question has 2 parts.

1. How(any tutorial would be perfect) can I play video in Android view which is not full screen?
2. Can I resize and change position of that view while the video is playing.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Right now your question is perfectly answerable by Googling around.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of video manipulation you definitely should have a look at [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html).

This view can be used to render a video via MediaPlayer and you can apply any transformation you want on it.

Here is a simple example of how to use it to play a video (with a dumb scaling animation):

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceTextureListener {

private static final String VIDEO_URL = "http://www.808.dk/pics/video/gizmo.mp4";

private MediaPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(VIDEO_URL));

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextureView videoView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    videoView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);


    // Scaling
    Animation scaling = new ScaleAnimation(0.2f, 1.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
    scaling.setDuration(2000);
    videoView.startAnimation(scaling);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    player.setSurface(new Surface(surface));
    player.start();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) { }

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) { return false; }

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) { }
}
```

With the following main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Note that this TextureView is only available for API level >= 14.

Comment: does support libraries include TextureView, because I want to use is on Android 2.2

Comment: I don't know, you'll have to check it out

Comment: hi @fiddler , may i know how to resize the video to fit into the resized TextureView, please help ... thanks in advance